# numpy: create array from a (index,value) dict

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a `dict` of the form: `{1: 5, 2: 1, 4: 6, 8: 9}`
and I want to convert it to an array of the form: `[0, 5, 1, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 9]`.

So the keys represent indexes into the array and the values of the `dict` at those indexes are the values of the array at the index.

Is there a nice and quick way to do this with numpy?

Comment: Please do *not* delete your question after it has received valid answers. Questions and answers here are supposed to benefit future readers too, not just the person who asked the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as `dict.get`.

```
>>> np.array([d.get(i, 0) for i in range(max(d) + 1)])
array([0, 5, 1, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 9])
```